# MySQL query challenge :)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get the last **ids** if **user_handle** is distinct with only 1 SQL query. Anyone knows how to do this?. I need that the SQL returns the ids (16149,16154). Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Challenge accepted marked it as a dupe :)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid This is basic `MAX() .. GROUP BY`.

Comment: Please share your attempt at this problem.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Linked question has accepted answer with both approaches max on column and max row per group

Comment: query: `select max(id) from handleuser group by user_handle order by id desc;`

Answer (score 2):

How about using `max()`?

```
select max(id), user_handle
from t
group by user_handle;
```

Comment: Ohhh, thank you, that is the solution.